# How to set bulletspan to a string in edittext at a leading margin?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I have a edittext and some buttons like bold italics underline bullets. Now when i select some text and press any button then using spannable string i am applying that particular span to that portion of the edittext like bold italics underline etc.

I am trying to put Bulletspan in edittext. Here is the code i use to put bullet span:-

```
s.setSpan(new BulletSpan(), text.getSelectionStart(), text.getSelectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

where text is my reference to the Edittext.

Now the issue is that I want that my bulleted text should come at some leading margin space or indentation from start like it comes in any text editor like MS Word.

Comment: Try to set the padding of your edittext in your xml file as `android:paddingLeft="10dp"`

Comment: I am using spannable string so for a particular text i want this, not for the whole edittext

Comment: Please brief your question more. What is your actual text and for which text you want spannable?

Comment: I have edited my question. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

Just tell [`BulletSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/BulletSpan.html#BulletSpan%28int%29) how much leading space you want. This example would give you 16dp leading space on the first and subsequent lines (like in the text editors you mentioned).

```
new BulletSpan(16);
```